# Function not returning the output in R

Tags: r, function

I have a function that takes a vector and returns some output.

```
my.function <- function(x){

   if (1 %in% x) {

     first.data <- data.frame(a = c(1, 2), b = c("a", "b"))
     return(first.data)    
   }

   if (2 %in% x){

   second.data <- data.frame(a = c("I", "II"), b = c("a", "b"))
   return(second.data) 
}}

my.function(x = c(1, 2))
  a b
  1 a
  2 b
```

Why does my function not return both `first.data` as well as `second.data`?

Comment: Do you mean `lapply(c(1, 2), my.function)`? Or `Vectorize(my.function, SIMPLIFY = F)` your function.

Comment: functions end after the first return has been done.

Comment: @missuse does it mean I can only have a single `return` command in a function and not multiple `return`?

Comment: You can have as many as you want/need, but understand that when the conditions for one of them have been meet the function will return the output without going forward.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simple call the function using `lapply` as follow:

```
lapply(1:2,my.function)
```

Output:

```
[[1]]
  a b
1 1 a
2 2 b

[[2]]
   a b
1  I a
2 II b
```

**If you would like to follow your approach then:**

```
 my.function <- function(x){
  for(i in 1:length(x)){ # This will call for each element in x
  if (1 %in% x) {
    first.data <- data.frame(a = c(1, 2), b = c("a", "b"))
    data = (first.data)    # Store intermediate result to data
  }

  if (2 %in% x){

    second.data <- data.frame(a = c("I", "II"), b = c("a", "b"))
    data=rbind(data,second.data) # Row wise bind the result
  }
    return(data) # Return the data
 }
}
my.function(x = c(1, 2))
```

Output:

```
    a b
 1  1 a
 2  2 b
 3  I a
 4 II b
```

Answer (score 3):

Whenever `return` statement executed, it won't execute next steps in a function. If you want to return both the outputs, use `return` to send the final output.

```
my.function <- function(x){
    first.data<-data.frame()
    second.data<-data.frame()
    if (1 %in% x) {
    first.data <- data.frame(a = c(1, 2), b = c("a", "b"))
    }

    if (2 %in% x){
        second.data <- data.frame(a = c("I", "II"), b = c("a", "b"))
    }
    return(list(first.data,second.data))
}
```

Comment: You mean do `return(first.data)` and `return(second.data)` in the end.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
my.function <- function(x){
first.data <- data.frame() 
second.data <- data.frame()

if (1 %in% x) {
 first.data <- data.frame(a = c(1, 2), b = c("a", "b"))   
}

if (2 %in% x){
   second.data <- data.frame(a = c("I", "II"), b = c("a", "b"))
}
list(first.data, second.data) # last element not declared is returned.
}
```

No need for `return`.

Keep in mind that if the `if-statement` is evaluated as `FALSE`, it will throw an error because the function won't find `first.data` or `second.data`.